# highlight searched text fetched from php ajax search using up and down key

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Iam trying to toggle through search result fetched from ajax result set. Actually the problem is onkeyup and onkeydown its not going up and down through search result which is quite frustrating. However, code which i tried are as follows:-

**Code:-**

```
<input type="search" class="searchnews" name="news" autocomplete="off" />
<div id="suggestion-list"></div>
<style>
 .selected {background: #EAEAEA;}
</style>
<script>
  $('.searchnews').keyup(function(e){
    $('input[name="hidden_news"]').val('');                         
    $('input[name="hidden_news"]').val($.trim($(this).val()));
    if(e.keyCode!=40 && e.keyCode!=38){
            var str = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax/getnews.php',
            data:'str='+str,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.length <= 2){
                    $("#suggestion-list").css('display','none');
                }
                else{
                    $("#suggestion-list").html('');
                    $("#suggestion-list").css('display','block');
                    $("#suggestion-list").append(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $("#suggestion-list ul li").removeClass("selected");
        if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
            selected.siblings().last().addClass("selected");
        } else {
            selected.prev().addClass("selected");
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $("#suggestion-list ul li").removeClass("selected");
        selected.next().addClass("selected");
        if (selected.next().length == 0) {
            selected.siblings().first().addClass("selected");
        } else {
            selected.next().addClass("selected");
        }
    }   
  });
</script>

**getnews.php**

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['str']) && $_POST['str']!=''){
        $str=$_POST['str'];
        $str1 = explode(' ',$str);
        foreach($str1 as $st){
        $sql[] =" title like '%".$st."%'";
        }
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE ".implode('and',$sql)." or  title like '%".$str."%'");
        //$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsupdate WHERE title LIKE \"%$str%\" and status='1' ORDER BY published_date DESC");
        $i=0;
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    echo '<ul>';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $i++;
        if($i==1){
        ?>
                <li class="selected"><a style="color:#030303;" target="_blank" >
                <span class="text"><?php echo preg_replace("/$str/i",'<span class="highlight">'.$str.'</span>',$row['title']); ?></span>
                </a></li>
        <?php   
        }
        else{
        ?>
            <li><a style="color:#030303;" target="_blank">
            <span class="text"><?php echo preg_replace("/$str/i",'<span class="highlight">'.$str.'</span>',$row['title']); ?>
            </span>
            </a></li>
        <?php
        }   
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Please help me out to rectify this problem. Thank You.

Comment: Have you looked at JQuery UI Autocomplete? I believe it satisfies what you are trying to accomplish. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: @DevinH. thanks man... for your reference and it quietly helped me a lot. But iam trying to do it manually using jquery.

Comment: The code looks like it should work. Can you add alert/console.log statements and see if those events are being raised?

Comment: @ParthShah Yeah your are right. The code works but the problem is when i keydown the selected li element goes next of next instead of its next li element.

Answer (score 2):

Jason, can you please remove the line I have commented out from your code and tell me what happens when you do that?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $("#suggestion-list ul li").removeClass("selected");
        if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
            selected.siblings().last().addClass("selected");
        } else {
            selected.prev().addClass("selected");
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $("#suggestion-list ul li").removeClass("selected");
        //selected.next().addClass("selected");
        if (selected.next().length == 0) {
            selected.siblings().first().addClass("selected");
        } else {
            selected.next().addClass("selected");
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: thanks buddy. It seems your rectification code works.